# using invoke-sqlcmd to call .sql script w/o restart after sql installation

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

In short, I am running a silent install of SQL Server 2016 using a *.ini file. At the end of the installation, I must restart to use any sort of sqlcmd/invoke-sqlcmd to call a SQL file.

Does anyone know of a method (preferably PowerShell) that can forgo a restart and run those commands?

Comment: Questions about application installation issues and such are off-topic at SO. Try ServerFault or SuperUser instead.

Comment: What error do you get? Is the service started?

Comment: @Charlieface I am notified in the prompt window that I'll need to restart the VM for installation to complete. 

I ask because I've seen .exe's that install sql with an instance then add a database w/o a restart.

Comment: Questions about application installation issues are off-topic at SO.